# Can I learn ski jumping in Japan?

Tags: japan, destinations, winter-sports

Since visiting Calgary Olympic Park and seeing their exhibit on [ski jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski_jumping) within the ski jumping tower, I've wanted to have a go at the sport, and Japan is the closest country to me (along with South Korea) that's into the sport.

Currently I know that lots of Japanese [schoolkids](http://www.snowjapanforums.com/index.php/topic/20665-nordic-ski-jumping-lessons-in-japan/page__view__findpost__p__418185) learn ski jumping, and that English-language tourism sites mention ski jumping hills as sightseeing attractions (eg [Okurayama in Sapporo](http://www.yamasa.org/japan/english/destinations/hokkaido/sapporo_ski_jump.html) and [Hakuba](http://www.vill.hakuba.nagano.jp/~us/attractions-olympic-facilities.html)).

What I don't know is whether it's possible to book ski jumping lessons (as in take lessons in the middle of the season for a week or so as part of a trip to Japan), or whether you'd have to be part of a sports club that operates for a whole season.

There doesn't seem to be any information in English about learning ski jumping in Japan, but maybe that's because people assume foreigners aren't interested in it.

Answers describing specific locations outside of Japan where it's possible to learn ski jumping are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in Japan - my Japanese isn't that great, and search results are mainly about an apparently new fad called "water jump", which seems to consist of riding a snowboard down a rather small ramp into a lake or pool.

Here's two event agencies offering two-day ski jumping lessons in Germany or Austria:

- http://www.jochen-schweizer.de/geschenk/ski-springen,default,pd.html
- http://www.mydays.de/originelle-geschenkideen/skispringen/skispringen-wochenendkurs-lauscha.html